# assigning value from object without specifying the index

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let us say I have an object below and I have 2 variable. The length of the object is always fixed.

I wanted to assign the object index attribute value to variable A and object index 1  to variable B.

I can do like `A = data[0].attributeValue;` and  `B = data[1].attributeValue;`

but is there a better and clean way to do this ? Thanks for any help or any idea. Appreciated.

#sample output

```
A = 'Test A'
B = 'Test B'
```

#sample variable

```
let A = '';
let B = '';
```

#sample object

```
 data =  [
        {
            "id": 13,
            "type": "1",
            "attributeValue": "Test A"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "type": "2",
            "attributeValue": "Test B"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: You want to define two variables, and you've done it in two lines. It doesn't get better than that. If you want other ideas, you could publish your code to the code review stack exchange - there might be some other approaches if the context of your whole script is included.

Comment: so you mean to say that is already a better solution Sir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but it won't help much .. well maybe a little:

```js
data = [{
    "id": 13,
    "type": "1",
    "attributeValue": "Test A"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "type": "2",
    "attributeValue": "Test B"
  }
]

var [{attributeValue: A}, {attributeValue: B}] = data;
console.log(A, B)
```